# How to avoid Word Macro running too slow and sometimes causing APP collapse?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Every time I ran this macro for a word document with 100 to 150 pages, I need to wait for minutes and sometimes the screen will turn into black. Since the .txt file contains 769 words, how to speed up the processing time?

```
Sub proofreading()

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
Dim arrStr() As String, InputStr As String
Fn = FreeFile
Open "G:\Proofreaders\PR.txt" For Input As #Fn
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While Not EOF(Fn)
    Line Input #Fn, InputStr
    If Len(InputStr) > 0 And Mid(InputStr, 1, 1) <> "'" Then
        arrStr = Split(InputStr, ",")

        Call ReplaceText(arrStr(0), arrStr(1))
    End If
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #Fn
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
Function ReplaceText(Src As String, Rpl As String)
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = Src
    .Replacement.Text = Rpl
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchByte = True
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Function
```

Hello all, I have a macro for replacing text according to a .txt file in Microsoft Word. This macro is for replacing texts in a Word Document with 100 to 150 pages. Since it contains 769 words, the screen will temporarily turned into black when the macro is processing. Even though it can ran successfully every time after 45 seconds to 1 min, I still want to improve it to avoid the blackscreen, no-response, and the speed of the Macro. Does anyone have any methods enhancing the processing speed of the following macro? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro is incredibly inefficient as a result of using Selection. Re-specifying the static variables on each loop in also inefficient. Try:

```
Sub FndRepDemo()
' Turn Off Screen Updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, FRList As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, SBar As Boolean
' Store current Status Bar status, then switch on
SBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar: Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Set DocSrc = Documents.Open("G:\Proofreaders\EngPR.txt", ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
With DocSrc
  .Range.Find.Execute FindText:="[^13]{1,}", Replacewith:="^p", MatchWildcards:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  FRList = .Range.Text
  .Close False
End With
Set DocSrc = Nothing
j = UBound(Split(FRList, vbCr)) - 1
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .Forward = True
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchByte = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .MatchFuzzy = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  'Process all F/R pairs
  For i = 0 To j
    'Give a progress report
    k = Int(i / j * 100)
    If k <> l Then
      l = k
      Application.ScreenRefresh
      Application.StatusBar = "% Processed: " & l
    End If
    'Exclude empty lines
    If InStr(Split(FRList, vbCr)(i), ",") > 0 Then
      .Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(i), ",")(0)
      .Replacement.Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(i), ",")(1)
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
    'Give Word some housekeeping time
    If i Mod 50 = 0 Then DoEvents
  Next
End With
' Restore original Status Bar status
Application.DisplayStatusBar = SBar
' Restore Screen Updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: If you're using a system with non-English regional settings, you'll need to change:

```
"[^13]{1,}"
```

to:

```
"[^13]{1;}"
```

Comment: Thank you master! I tried to ran your macro but it cannot run successfully due to Subscript out of range (Error 9) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9)

Code with issue: .Replacement.Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(i), ",")(1)

Comment: As I understand it, your text file has a line for each Find/Replace pair, with the Find/Replace expressions on each line separated by a comma. Correct? If so, the error is most likely due to your text file having incomplete Find/Replace pairs and/or empty lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. My .txt file is like this:                                                                

analyse,analyze
organisation,organization

While the left one is wrong, the right one is right. The macro should according to this .txt file to auto find the left column words and then replace them as the right column one.

Comment: OK, but what separates analyse,analyze from organisation,organization - a line break or a space?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. there is no line break or space to separate the right and wrong words.

Comment: I'll ask again - What separates the *pairs* of words (i.e analyse,analyze is one pair, which se separated from organisation,organization, which is another pair)?

Comment: Please check the .txt file at :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1st4xE-ji5Jd0Gh0_4y0HPZOfzea42fGS/view?usp=share_link

Comment: As I suggested in my first reply to your ' Subscript out of range' issue, the problem is caused by your text file having empty lines - three of them at the end. I have modified the code to accommodate that. I've also added code to give a progress report and let Word do some housekeeping.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried to ran your macro, it ran smoothly and showing the percentage processing. However, there is no words being replaced. For example, I typed the word "actualise" and it supposed to be replaced as "actualize". But the macro didn't replace it. How to edit the code so it can replace the words? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It seems the new lines in your text file weren't being recognised as paragraph breaks. Code revised. Try it now.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! It ran smooth but still don't replace any words. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Except for some anomalies due to your use of various forms of the same word in the wrong sequence, the code works 100% for me... Aside from those anomolies every 'Find' string in the document that is listed in your text file gets replaced with the 'Replace' string

Comment: It rans well eventually. Words are not enough to express my gratitude. Thank you so much for your help these days!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid selecting the text every time (which is very "expensiv") by using `ThisDocument.Content`:

```vb
Function ReplaceText(Src As String, Rpl As String)

With ThisDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting

    .Text = Src
    .Replacement.Text = Rpl
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchByte = True
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Function
```

Sometimes it could help to reset the undo-stack regularly - if you have a lot of changes: `ThisDocument.UndoClear`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to run the Macro edited by you but I found the macro cannot automatically delete and replace specified words according to the .txt file. I replaced the "Function" part only. Is there any step(s) that should be corrected? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your issue

Comment: @terenceli35 'I replaced the "Function part only"' Pretty sure that was Ike's intention. In other words, you still need the part of your code that iterates through the file of "find,replace" pairs.

Comment: @jonsson I replace the "Function part" and also kept the part of my code that iterates through the file of "find, replace" pairs. It ran so quick but the result is not the same as the original one. The original one can find and replace the texts according to the .txt file in a slow speed, while the new code cannot do so.

Comment: Maybe you have to use `ActiveDocument.Content` ... if the code is not running in the document where the replace should happen